# Working with beforeunload listener with Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, onbeforeunload, nuxt3

Anyone knows how to unbind **`beforeunload`** event listener in Nuxt3?

So, I have this code in my **`create.vue`** page (I'm using composition API):

```
const preventNavigation = (e) => {
  var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                          + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', preventNavigation, false)

onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from , next) => {
  console.log(from.name)
  if (from.name === 'albums-edit-token' && !isSaveAlbum.value) {
    const answer = window.confirm('This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave — information you’ve entered may not be saved.')
    if (answer) next()
    else next(false)
  } else next()
})
```

What it does is, it will prevent the user to change the route (using the `onBeforeRouteLeave`) or leave the page by exiting or refreshing the page (using the `window.addEventListener`).

The problem is, when the user navigates to another route, it will trigger the `onBeforeRouteLeave`, and if he chooses to leave, `window.addEventlistener` still remains and stays not triggered. Making the next page prevents the user to leave, which is not the expected behavior.

Anyone knows how to unbind the `beforeunload` event listener? I've already searched google and stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.